# Bootstrap 5.0.3 custom css doesnt work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to make the left middle right buttons from this [source.](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/rounded-buttons)

So I started with

> npm install bootstrap@3

After that I installed jQuery because of the description of the demo page

> npm install jquery

My code is exactly the same as from the demo page but all I get is this:

[image]

```css
.btn-round-lg{
border-radius: 22.5px;
}
.btn-round{
border-radius: 17px;
}
.btn-round-sm{
border-radius: 15px;
}
.btn-round-xs{
border-radius: 11px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Left</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>                     
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5.0.3? Considering Bootstrap 4 isn't yet out I have no idea how you're using that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ppL8stkv/

```css
.btn-round-lg{
  border-radius: 22.5px;
}
.btn-round{
  border-radius: 17px;
}
.btn-round-sm{
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.btn-round-xs{
  border-radius: 11px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Left</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Right</button>
        </div>                     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might have missed `bootstrap library`. Check the jsfiddle.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: omg thank you thought it would be enough to run "npm install bootstrap@3"